# I don't manage to build barebox for STM32 microcontroller

Tags: makefile, stm32, barebox

I've been carefully following this tutorial : https://www.barebox.org/doc/latest/boards/stm32mp.html to flash Barebox on a STM32 MCU but I'm stuck at the "Building barebox" step.

When I type `make ARCH=arm stm32mp_defconfig` I see the makefile executes without any error. Here are the logs :

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/menu.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/util.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

but at the end I don't have any image in the `images/` folder.

I tried to proceed in the tutorial but I clearly see in the next step that I need .img files in the `images/` folder...

I feel totally lost since I followed the tutorial very carefully and nothing indicates me when I could have done an error...

Otherwise, if someone knows a more simple way to flash Barebox in a STM32 MCU hmu. I've already spent hours on this and this tutorial makes me feel lost af.

Answer (score 0):

barebox uses Kbuild, the Linux kernel build system. `make ARCH=arm stm32mp_defconfig` will configure barebox appropriately for the STM32MP by creating a new `.config` file with all the settings. Afterwards you need to just call `make` to actually build this configuration:

```
make ARCH=arm
```

And then you will have the images built. This is described [in detail in the barebox documentation](https://www.barebox.org/doc/latest/user/barebox.html#compilation). The board documentation you looked at is like a quick start which assumes familiarity with the main documentation, but I have nevertheless [just sent a patch amending it](https://lore.barebox.org/barebox/20220502065346.1804502-1-ahmad@a3f.at/T/#t).

---

With this one extra `make call, you should now have images for a couple of STM32MP boards, but these are application processors (with MMU, no built-in flash, some with GPU, ... etc.) and not microcontrollers. There is no mainline support for STM32 MCUs. I have hacked together some support for the STM32F429I-DISCO, but I have yet to upstream it. What board do you want to run barebox on?